# 0x80072f7d error while installing python in W7

Tags: windows-7, installation, python

I have installed Windows SP1 and tried to install KB2999226 from microsoft update but it is giving error "THIS UPDATE IS NOT APPLICABLE TO THIS COMPUTER".

Mainly i am not able resolve the 0x80072f7d error

Answer (score 0):

> I have installed Windows SP1 and tried to install KB2999226 from microsoft update but it is giving error "This Update Is Not Applicable to This Computer".

[KB2999226](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB2999226%20) can only be installed on **Windows Server 2008** and **Windows Vista**.  You cannot install Windows Vista updates on Windows 7.

If you are attempting to install Update for [Universal C Runtime in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows) be sure you are downloading the installer compatiable with **Windows 7 Service Pack 1**.